# ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! even when we have unique index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I asked a question last days and I got the accepted response for that. Here is the question,

[Group the dataframe based on ids and stick the values of ids to each other with mean of the last days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71593600/group-the-dataframe-based-on-ids-and-stick-the-values-of-ids-to-each-other-with)

But, the problem is that when I want to apply this code to a large dataframe, it gives me an error as `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`. I've tried to check the index of my data frame by `df.columns.value_counts()` and as follow, all of the count for my dataframe is `1`. my dataframe has 30 columns with 3000 rows. **point_id, date, and Temperatures** are columns.

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you share your data to check my answer :)

Comment: Yes. Its possible. But, I don't know where I should upload it?

Comment: WeTransfer. You can share without create account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 254 rows where you have at least 2 data points for the same (point_id, date). What do you want to do with records for a same (point_id, date)? You can group this data and keep the mean, for instance.

Here is the list:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dft.csv', index_col=0)
counts = df.value_counts(['point_id', 'date'], sort=False).loc[lambda x: x > 1]
```

Comment: Thank you Corralien. Yes. I have some mistake in the code and now it works. I don't want to delete the question, for some limitation, I delete the link of the data. Could you also please delete the output of your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. There are two right answers for that question. I've checked the responses and put a comment for other response. Finally, in my code, I've used your solution. I will edit the question and will accept your response. Thanks a lot. Your responses save my weeks and help me a lot.